# Python function return returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have written the below code using decorator and the code is returning None when I am expecting an integer or float value. the function (num(a, b)) returns a value when I don't use decorator and the issue comes when I use decorator. Can someone please clarify why the code is returning None. Below is the code:

```
def decor(func):
    def inner(a, b):
        if a <= b:
            print("If executed")
            a, b = b, a
            c = a - b
            print(c)
            return c
        else:
            print("else executed")
            func(a, b)
    return inner


def num(a, b):
    print("Function executed")
    d = (a - b)
    print(d)
    return d


num = decor(num)

print(num(3, 5))  # this is returning a value
print(num(3, 1))  # this is returning None
```

Comment: You want `return func` rather than just `func` in the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `inner` function has no `return` statement in the `else` branch. Presumably you meant to write `return func(a, b)`?

Comment: This is my first stackoverflow query and the community is so quick to help, thanks. I fixed the code now by updating else statement to return func(a,b) and it worked...